# In Pyspark how to iterate through each row in a data frame do calculations retain the value and use in next step by partition

Tags: pyspark, sas, window, partition, retained-in-memory

Sample Input:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

How do I code in Pyspark for the above problem

Problem description:

The respective code will iterate through each row in the dataset partitioned by coll_id_latest. For all the first record total_alloc will be zero and for rest based on the If else condition new column final to be created. The total_alloc to be retained and to be used in next iteration.I tried in pyspark writing a for loop to iterate through each row which is very in-efficient. And on big datasets it gives memory errors. Is there a better way of writing or any suggestions to how write the pyspark code? Can any write sample code for me to refer.I have tried writing a for loop which is very in efficient and takes time to execute any better methods using window method, but need to retain a value and use in next iteration.`

Below is the SAS code:

```
data x;
    set y;
    by coll_id_latest;
    retain total_alloc  0;
    if first.coll_id_latest then
        do;total_alloc=0;end;
    if lowcase(acct)="primary" then
                        do;
                            if  exposure not in (.,0) and total_alloc<pba1 then
                                    final_pba   =   min(exposure,(pba1-total_alloc));
                            else    final_pba   =   0;                          
                        end;
    if  lowcase(acct)="secondary" 
                    and lowcase(suff_ind)^='y' and total_alloc < pba1 then
                        do;
                            final_pba   =min(max(pba1-total_alloc,0),exposure);                         
                        end;
                    total_alloc=sum(total_alloc,final_pba);
run;
```

Comment: One is a running total. The remainder are flags that are set on each. You can convert this in multiple steps to pyspark, but it helps if you provide sample data and explain the logic for python programmers who may not understand SAS.

Comment: Hi @Reeza I have edited an example. I am looking to code the same logic in PYSPARK

Comment: Hi community any suggestions